# doctrine2 bring me back 1 row on sonata admin 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

in my case : Symfony2.8 and Sonata admin 3

in sonata admin list , i use custom query to show my result

here is my code :

```
 public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);



        $query->groupBy(
            $query->getRootAliases()[0] .'.ip',
            $query->getRootAliases()[0] .'.title'
        );


        return $query;
    }
```

but when i go to the list i got error : get me back more than one row

here is the error :

```
The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().
```

i want to get all rows on list how to do that ?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code, but could you please provide more data like your Entity, the query you're comparing with and some data (e.g. what do you expect? the one dataset, or the three?).

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?